# Array-based unordered list implementation in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented

This class, `UnorderedList`, implements an Unordered list in Java. In this class, duplicates are allowed. `remove(argument)` will delete the first occurrence of the argument. I was wondering to add other functions named `add(int index, int data)` and `set(int index, int data)` or not. Since the class is unordered, I thought I would not need it. The size of the class is limited although that does not concern me (`UnorderedLinkedList` coming up next).

I tried to make sure all the functionality and behaviours are correct. If this class is lacking any method(s) and/or correct usage of exception and anything else please comment below. Any kind of suggestions and advice is appreciated.

```
//Node class

package lists.arrayLists.unorderedList;

public class Node
{
    private int data;

    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}

//UnorderedList class

package lists.arrayLists.unorderedList;

import java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class UnorderedList
{
    public static final int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    private int size;
    private Node[] nodeElements;
    private int currentIndex;                           // to navigate/iterate over list

    public UnorderedList()
    {
        nodeElements = new Node[MAX_SIZE];
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    {
        return (size() == MAX_SIZE);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (size() == 0);
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean add(int data)
    {
        try
        {
            Node node = new Node(data);
            nodeElements[size++] = node;
            return true;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    public void remove(int data)
    {
        int index = locate(data);
        try
        {
            nodeElements[index] = nodeElements[size() - 1];
            size--;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    public boolean find(int data)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        try
        {
            if(locate(data) >= 0)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            return found;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    // locate function looks for an element in the array, if there is one then returns its index
    private int locate(int data)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int index = -1;
        boolean found = false;
        while (i < size() && !found)
        {
            if (data == nodeElements[i].getData())
            {
                found = true;
                index = i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return index;
     }

    //Navigator methods

    public void reset()
    {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return (currentIndex == size());
    }

    public void next()
    {
        if (!hasNext()) currentIndex++;
    }

    public int currentElement()
    {
        return nodeElements[currentIndex].getData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `Log4j` instead of `System.out.println()` with some meaningful message to the user. Also, you can implement `locate()` method as mentioned below to avoid initializing the flag

```
private int locate(int data)
{
    int i = 0;
    int index = -1;
    while (i < size())
    {
        if (data == nodeElements[i].getData())
        {
           index = i;
           break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return index;
 }
```

Change: Use `break;` to come out of the loop rather than using flag to check it.

Comment: Please summarize the changes you made. Code only answers are considered off-topic.

Comment: @t3chb0t, done:).

Answer (score 2):

- `locate` never throws, so what `find` expects to catch? Consider

  ```
  public boolean find(int data) {
      return locate(data) >= 0;
  }
  ```
- `locate` is overcomplicated. Consider

  ```
  private int locate(data) {
      for (int index = 0; index < size(); index++) {
          if (data == nodeElements[i].getData()) {
              return index;
          }
      }
      return -1;
  ```
- `reset`, `hasNext`, and `next` do not belong to the list class; they are the methods of a list iterator. For starters, notice that your implementation only allows one list traversal at a time.

  That said, the semantics of `hasNext()` is wrong. The condition `currentIndex == size()` means that there is *no* next. A client of your class would be badly confused.

  Along the same line, `next()` should not silently ignore the end-of-list condition.

Comment: how do I separate Iterator class from this class? Any demonstration or link to this solution would be very helpful. @vnp

Comment: @HamidurRahman I don't know Java conventions, but normally you'd define an `iterator` class holding `currentIndex`, with `next` and `hasNext` methods, and pass your list to its constructor,

Comment: Thanks. I will look for it and find the solution and then post it in this comment section. Is that okay? @vnp

Comment: @HamidurRahman Better post a follow-up question.