# Implementation of generic unordered list in java

Tags: java, object-oriented, generics, iterator, interface

This question is a follow-up question of [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196083/array-based-unordered-list-implementation-in-java/196095?noredirect=1#comment377792_196095) question. These features are added to the new class -

- `Generic` class
- User is capable of setting the size
- `List interface` has been added
- `Iterator` class has been added

As of now I still have some questions after developing this class.

- Does this `list interface` have enough methods/behavior?
- Why do I have to type cast from `next()` while returning data?
- When I am testing this class I have to do this `Iterator<Integer> itr = ((UnorderedList) ul).iterator();` why?

[Thanks to him](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40480/vnp) to open my eyes to design a class to iterate over a structure. My prof of Data Structure even did not specify or taught students important things like this.

If this class is still lacking anything then as always suggestions and advice are appreciated.

**//List interface**

```
package lists.arrayLists;

public interface List<T>
{
    boolean isFull();
    boolean isEmpty();
    boolean add(T data);
    void remove(T data);
    boolean find(T data);
    int size();
}
```

**// Unordered List class**

```
package lists.arrayLists.unorderedList;

import lists.arrayLists.List;
import java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class UnorderedList<T> implements List<T>, Iterable<T>
{
    private static int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    private int size;
    private Node<T>[] nodeElements;

    public UnorderedList()
    {
        nodeElements = new Node[MAX_SIZE];
    }

    public UnorderedList(int capacity)
    {
        MAX_SIZE = capacity;
        nodeElements = new Node[MAX_SIZE];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFull()
    {
        return (size() == MAX_SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (size() == 0);
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T data)
    {
        try
        {
            Node<T> node = new Node<>(data);
            nodeElements[size++] = node;
            return true;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(T data)
    {
        int index = locate(data);
        try
        {
            nodeElements[index] = nodeElements[size() - 1];
            size--;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean find(T data)
    {
        return (locate(data) >= 0);
    }

    private int locate(T data)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < size(); index++)
        {
            if (data == nodeElements[index].getData())
            {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return new ULIterator<T>();
    }

    private class ULIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
    {
        private int currentIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return (currentIndex < size());
        }

        @Override
        public T next()
        {
            if(hasNext())
            {
                return (T)nodeElements[currentIndex++].getData();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**// Node class**

```
package lists.arrayLists.unorderedList;

public class Node<T>
{
    private T data;

    public Node(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not implement `java.util.List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this list interface have enough methods/behavior?

Yes, it is enough. If you want to extend it consider implementing `java.util.Collection` interface.

> Why do I have to type cast from next() while returning data?
>
> When I am testing this class I have to do this Iterator itr = ((UnorderedList) ul).iterator(); why?

Those two questions are related. You need a cast to `UnorderedList` since you didn't put `iterator()` function in your `List` interface. And cast for `next()` is required since you used `(UnorderedList) ul` instead of `(UnorderedList<Integer>) ul`.

If `MAX_SIZE` is a constant it should have `final` modifier and shouldn't be changed in `UnorderedList(int capacity)`. You might use nodeElements.length instead.
`Node` class looks pointless, there is nothing wrong with using `T[] nodeElements` or  better `Object[] nodeElements`, since generic arrays are tricky to construct.

You also shouldn't catch `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you can just check if index is valid before accessing it.